# Teechart's DrawValue

Tags: c#, teechart

If I have a candle series drawn on the teechart, and I change the last candle's CloseValue, the candle does not automatically update on the chart. I don't really want to invalidate the whole chart to show it because if there are a lot of candles, that's slow. I thought the DrawValue method of the Candle series would solve this, but it seems that it actually redraws the whole chart as well. Is there a way to update/redraw on screen just that one candle?

I know when I was doing this in Delphi 5 the candle seemed to update without redrawing the whole chart - although maybe the whole chart updates were fast enough that it just seemed that way. In general, it seems that C#'s Teechart draws are 3 to 5 times slower than the Delphi 5 VCL Teechart's draws...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the method that allow refresh only the series, RefreshSeries, as do in next line of code:

```
  candle1.RefreshSeries();
```

Could you tell me, if it works for you? If you have any problems please let me know.

Update information to answer next question:

> Ok, I guess I am not explaining myself well here, Sandra. Let me try
>   again. Let's say I have a chart that has only one series - 30,000
>   candles. Let's say I show ALL candles on the chart. Redrawing all 30K
>   candles takes time. Let's say the code changes only ONE candle - the
>   last one. Is there any way to just repaint that little portion of the
>   chart that has the new candle, and not repaint the whole chart in
>   order to show the new change? I tried Invalidate function passing it
>   the candle's rectangle, but it seems that Invalidate() and
>   Invalidate(rect) produce exactly same results.

Can you tell us which version of TeeChart are you using?. In the other hand, I have made a simple code where I have modified the CloseValue and I have released that isn't  necessary repaint, redraw or refresh Series because the value is updated automatically. I have made the test using last version of TeeChartFor.Net Build number [4.1.2012.01312] and next code:

```
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Candle candleSeries1;
Random r;
double tmpOpen;
double tmpClose;
int count;
DateTime dt;
TimeSpan ts;
private void InitializeChart()
{
    tChart1.Aspect.View3D=false;
    tChart1.AutoRepaint = false;
     r = new Random();
    candleSeries1.Clear();
    candleSeries1.XValues.DateTime = true;
    candleSeries1.GetHorizAxis.Labels.Angle = 90;
    count = 0;
    dt = DateTime.Today;
    ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    candleSeries1.Pen.Visible = false;
    for (int t=0;t<30000;t++)
    {
        tmpOpen = r.Next(100);
        tmpClose = tmpOpen - r.Next(100);
            ++count;
            candleSeries1.Add(dt,tmpOpen,tmpOpen + r.Next(50),
                tmpClose -r.Next(50),tmpClose);
        dt += ts;
    }
    tChart1.AutoRepaint = true;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmpOpen = r.Next(100);
    tmpClose = tmpOpen - r.Next(100);
    candleSeries1[candleSeries1.LastVisibleIndex].Close = tmpOpen;

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: It works in the sense of doing the same thing visually but I don't think it is much faster than refreshing the chart. The whole point here is that there are a lot of candles in the series (30K or so) and if they are all shown redrawing is fairly slow. Can't just redraw the last candle?  Also - when I update CloseValues, isn't it supposed to update itself visually? AutoRepaint's are true...

Comment: Hello,

The RefreSeries() method is faster than tChart.Draw, because it recalculates all dependent Series points again but doesn't repaint all the Canvas. There is other method that can be useful for you when you want update only values of Series. It is checkDataSource method that refreshes all Series point values, either from database Tables, Queries or Series points.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want improve the performance and achieve your applications works more speed, first points is disable AutoRepaint when you add values, for this I recommend you take a look in the realtime example, you can find in this link: 
http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php

If using my recommendations doesn't  help you to solve the problem, please send us your code and we try to improve the performance of you applications.

Comment: Ok, I guess I am not explaining myself well here, Sandra. Let me try again. Let's say I have a chart that has only one series - 30,000 candles. Let's say I show ALL candles on the chart. Redrawing all 30K candles takes time. Let's say the code changes only ONE candle - the last one. Is there any way to just repaint that little portion of the chart that has the new candle, and not repaint the whole chart in order to show the new change? I tried Invalidate function passing it the candle's rectangle, but it seems that Invalidate() and Invalidate(rect) produce exactly same results.

Comment: Sandra, also, while I have your attention - does using Direct2D with Teecharts allow me to have double-buffering like I can have with GDI+? I am placing transparent panels over the chart, and without double buffering to allow me to repaint background really fast, it won't work...

Comment: Hello, Please see my previous answer that I have updated by provide you a code where the CloseValues is update automatically.  Could you please test my code and confirm if it works or not  in your end?

Comment: About question by Direct2D, as is explained in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2009/09/29/comparing-direct2d-and-gdi.aspx.

Comment: When Windows was first designed, there was insufficient memory to allow every window to be stored in its own bitmap. As a result, GDI always rendered logically directly to the screen, with various clipping regions applied to ensure that it did not render outside of its window. In contract, Direct2D follows a model where the application renders to a back-buffer and the result is atomically “flipped” when the application is done drawing. This allows Direct2D to handle animation scenarios much more fluidly that GDI can. therefore the double-buffering is done automatically. I hope will helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am going to be out of town for a few days, will respond when I get back.