# Realtime Charting - draw only changes possible?

Tags: .net, wpf, teechart

I'm using the teechart for .net for wpf (Version 4). 
Is there a possibilty to get teechart draw only the changes in data ?

Using a fastline series I tried with Option AutoRepaint Chart / Series / Invalidate after adding Points and so on.

But the more data is in the Chart, the more time it takes to draw because always the complete series is being drawn.

So what could be done to just draw the changes on update ? So when 100 Points are being added to the series just draw These 100 and not thousands of Points that are already on the Screen ...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you, taking a look in the discussion there is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101063/teecharts-drawvalue) where is talked about the similar problem as you have. The code I made in this example, is based in a Candle series but I think can help you, because only update the last data close value of candle series and you can use the same idea for a Fastline series,so, you can update the last data value added in  Fastline series. Could you confirm us if my suggestion works in your end?

Thanks,